# Why won't chatterbot python learn from our convos?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, chatterbot

I'm using ChatterBot in python and it enters the data into the Sqlite database but doesn't actually match it...

For example it says its adding a reply but then I can never get it to repeat it.

If I say What is your name... and it doesn't know then I reply  "it's mia" it never says its name is mia.

It can't even get basic stuff like to reply to what's up with not much unless its trained on data.

```
bot = ChatBot('Mia',read_only=False,
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
        logic_adapters=[

           {
              'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
              'default_response': '445653468',
              'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.10
            },
              'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation'#,
             #'chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter'
        ],
        database_uri='sqlite:///database.sqlite3'
      )
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(bot)

trainer.train(
    "chatterbot.corpus.english"
)
```

What is the issue here?

I have tried looking at the sqlite database and and telling it a lot of times the something over.
I have tried playing around with having no training data or deleting the database.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rbAq.png)

[Here is my console trying to debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJbHz.png)

It's seems it guesses it but then just spits out "don't know"

[Here is more debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGOZ.png)

Comment: I have read_only=False and still having issues.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score -1):

Turned out it was the version of chatterbot I was using it was buggy. I fixed issue by using stable version 1.0.0